# My game lags when I press button

Tags: actionscript-3, air, flash-builder, flash-cs5, flashdevelop

I have an app that I'm developing for iOS and Android using AS3.  I'm currently having several performance issues with this project. This is my very first app and game. So any type of feedback or insight is greatly appreciated. My game is a dirt bike wheelie game. It allows the user to press a button (gasPress) to wheelie upward and another button (brake) to wheelie downward. Once the "gasPress" button is pressed, a boolean "holdGas" is set to true. In my "gameLoop" (Enter_Frame event), the bike is rotated upward, IF "holdGas" is equal to true. The code for pressing the brake is the same, except it rotates the bike donward. I have buildings that slide across the screen, creating the illusion that the bike is moving. The building movie clips are cached as bitmap. I use two instances of the same building movie clip. Once the first clip slides off the stage, it's placed behind the other. In a recycling kind of mechanism lol. The problem I'm having with this is, when i press the "gasPress" button, it lags before wheelie/rotating upward. When it lags, the buildings moving in the background skips. It happens every time. So if you keep tapping the gasPress, (which is part of the gameplay) the objects on the screen keep jumping. It makes the game unplayable. I've tested the buttons by completely removing the code to move the bike upward/downward and the game still skips. I've noticed more of a skip or lag when the gas is pressed and the bike rotates upward. I currently have the frame rate set to 32, it did the same at 24.

```
public function TheGame() {
            //Connect to tapjoy's ad network
            //tjClass = new TapJoyClass();
            //stage.scaleMode = StageScaleMode.NO_SCALE;
            //stage.align = StageAlign.TOP_LEFT; 
            //Give game focus so the keyboard keys will work on computer
            stage.focus = this;
            globalStage = this.stage;
            //Checks if ScoreData and Bike data shared object has been created, if not it creates
            scoreInfo = SharedObject.getLocal ( "ScoreData" );
            bikeInfo = SharedObject.getLocal ( "BikeData" );
            //scoreInfo.clear ();
            //bikeInfo.clear ();
            mostSprocketsCollected = scoreInfo.data.mostSprocketsCollected;
            //Handling  background
            background1 = new Background;
            background2 = new Background;
            addChild ( background1 );
            addChild ( background2 );
            background1.cacheAsBitmap = true;
            background2.cacheAsBitmap = true;
            background1.mouseChildren = false;
            background1.mouseEnabled = false;
            background2.mouseChildren = false;
            background2.mouseEnabled = false;
            background1.x = background1.width;
            background2.x = background1.x + background2.width;
            //Handling buildings
            building1 = new Buildings;
            building2 = new Buildings;
            addChild ( building1 );
            addChild ( building2 );
            building1.cacheAsBitmap = true;
            building2.cacheAsBitmap = true;
            building1.mouseChildren = false;
            building1.mouseEnabled = false;
            building2.mouseChildren = false;
            building2.mouseEnabled = false;
            building1.x = building1.width;
            building2.x = building1.x + building2.width;
            //Choose which bike will be used
            if( bikeInfo.data.EquippedBike == undefined ){
                //Start off with original bike
                whichBike = "OriginalDirtBike";
                bikeInfo.data.BikeColor = "OriginalDirtBike";
            }else{
                whichBike = bikeInfo.data.EquippedBike;
            }
            if( whichBike == "Banshee" ){
                //Add far wheels first
                wheelClip2 = new Banshee_Far_WheelClip;
                addChild ( wheelClip2 );
                //wheelClip2. = 208.30;
                wheelClip2.y = 350;
                //Add Banshee
                bitmapBike = new Banshee_Bitmap ();
                bitmapBike.gotoAndStop ( bikeInfo.data.BikeColor );
                addChild ( bitmapBike );
                bitmapBike.y = 399.80;
                bitmapBike.x = 0;
                //Add frontWheels
                wheelClip = new Banshee_WheelClip ();
                wheelClip.backTire.frontFace.gotoAndStop ( bikeInfo.data.BikeColor );
                wheelClip.frontTire.frontFace.gotoAndStop ( bikeInfo.data.BikeColor );
                addChild ( wheelClip );
                wheelClip.x = 187.70;
                wheelClip.y = 399;
            }else if( whichBike == "SupermotoDRZ400" ){
                //Add Wheels
                wheelClip = new WheelClip ();
                wheelClip.backTire.gotoAndStop ( bikeInfo.data.BikeColor );
                wheelClip.frontTire.gotoAndStop ( bikeInfo.data.BikeColor );
                addChild ( wheelClip );
                wheelClip.x = 0;
                wheelClip.y = 409.45;
                //Add bike
                bitmapBike = new SuperMoto_Bitmap ();
                bitmapBike.gotoAndStop ( bikeInfo.data.BikeColor );
                addChild ( bitmapBike );
                bitmapBike.y = 399.80;
            }else if( whichBike == "OriginalDirtBike" ){
                //Add wheels
                wheelClip = new OriginalBike_WheelClip ();
                wheelClip.backTire.gotoAndStop ( bikeInfo.data.BikeColor );
                wheelClip.frontTire.gotoAndStop ( bikeInfo.data.BikeColor );
                addChild ( wheelClip );
                wheelClip.x = 0;
                wheelClip.y = 405;
                //Add Bike
                bitmapBike = new OriginalBike_Bitmap ();
                addChild ( bitmapBike );
                bitmapBike.gotoAndStop ( bikeInfo.data.BikeColor );
                bitmapBike.y = 399.80;
                //Add rider
                //rider = new Rider_Original_bitmap ();
                //addChild ( rider );
                //rider.y = 353.1
            }
            //bitmapBike.mouseChildren = false;
            //bitmapBike.mouseEnabled = false;
            //bitmapBike.cacheAsBitmapMatrix = bitmapBike.transform.concatenatedMatrix;
            //bitmapBike.cacheAsBitmap = true;
            //
            trace ( "bitmap bike : " + getSize ( bitmapBike) );

            //rider.cacheAsBitmapMatrix = rider.transform.concatenatedMatrix;
            //rider.cacheAsBitmap = true;
            rider.mouseChildren = false;
            rider.mouseEnabled = false;

            gasPress.addEventListener ( MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, hitGas );
            gasPress.addEventListener ( MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, releaseGas );
            brake.addEventListener ( MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, hitBrake );
            brake.addEventListener ( MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, releaseBrake );
            stage.addEventListener ( KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, useKeyboard);
            stage.addEventListener ( KeyboardEvent.KEY_UP, stopUseKeyboard);
            addEventListener ( Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, init );
            ScoreBoardFormat = new TextFormat ();
            ScoreBoardFormat.bold = true; 
            sprocketVector = new Vector.< MovieClip > ();
            sprocketPool = new SprocketPool( Sprocket, pool_SprocketAmount );
            stage.addEventListener ( Event.RESIZE, resizeObjects );
            stage.dispatchEvent( new Event( Event.RESIZE ) );
            if( Accelerometer.isSupported ){
                //on mobile device
            }else{
                //on desktop
                gravity = 15; // low values for phone
                dy = 60; // low values for phone
                backgroundDx = -160;
                buildingDx  = -300;
                dx  = 300; // speed and direction
            }
            //start bike off in a wheelie
            bitmapBike.rotation = -45;
            rider.rotation = -45;
            wheelClip.x = -15;
            rider.x = bitmapBike.x;
            //Add the first sprocket
            addSprocket();
        }

    //Following Functions are Gas and Brake related
        public function hitGas (e:MouseEvent){
            e.stopImmediatePropagation();
            holdGas = true;
            pressedBrake = "no";
        }
        public function hitBrake (e:MouseEvent){
            e.stopImmediatePropagation();
            pressedBrake = "yes"; 
        }
        public function releaseGas (e:MouseEvent){
            e.stopImmediatePropagation();
            holdGas = false;
        }
        public function releaseBrake (e:MouseEvent){
            e.stopImmediatePropagation();
            pressedBrake = "no"; 
        }




    //Game Loop
        public function gameLoop ( e:Event ):void{
            e.stopImmediatePropagation();
            var timePassed:int = getTimer()-lastTime;
            lastTime += timePassed;

            if ( whichBike == "SupermotoDRZ400" ){
                 //Keep wheels in position with the bike
                 wheelClip.rotation = bitmapBike.rotation;
                 wheelClip.x = bitmapBike.x;
                 //make tires spin
                 wheelClip.frontTire.rotation += 75*timePassed/1000;
                 wheelClip.backTire.rotation += 75*timePassed/1000;
                 rider.rotation = bitmapBike.rotation - 1;
                 rider.x = bitmapBike.x + 25;
            }else if ( whichBike == "OriginalDirtBike" ){
                //Keep wheels in position with the bike
                wheelClip.rotation = bitmapBike.rotation - 1.5;
                wheelClip.rotation = bitmapBike.rotation;
                wheelClip.x = bitmapBike.x + 16.5;
                //make tires spin
                wheelClip.frontTire.rotation += 75*timePassed/1000;
                wheelClip.backTire.rotation += 75*timePassed/1000;
                //rider
                rider.x = bitmapBike.x;
                rider.rotation = bitmapBike.rotation;
            }else if ( whichBike == "Banshee" ){
                rider.rotation = bitmapBike.rotation;
                rider.x = bitmapBike.x;
                //First wheels
                wheelClip.x = bitmapBike.x;
                wheelClip.rotation = bitmapBike.rotation;
                wheelClip.frontTire.frontFace.rotation += 75*timePassed/1000;
                wheelClip.frontTire.backFace.rotation  += 75*timePassed/1000;
                wheelClip.backTire.frontFace.rotation += 75*timePassed/1000;
                wheelClip.backTire.backFace.rotation  += 75*timePassed/1000;
                //second wheels
                wheelClip2.x = bitmapBike.x;
                wheelClip2.rotation = bitmapBike.rotation;
                wheelClip2.farBackTire.frontFace.rotation += 75*timePassed/1000;
                wheelClip2.farFrontTire.frontFace.rotation += 75*timePassed/1000;
                wheelClip2.farFrontTire.backFace.rotation += 75*timePassed/1000;
            }

            if( popUp != null ){
                this.setChildIndex ( popUp, this.numChildren - 2 );
            }
            this.setChildIndex ( rider, this.numChildren - 1 );
            //Stores the bikes current rotation point
            var currRotation = bitmapBike.rotation;

            //make shadow follow bike
            var bikeX:int = bitmapBike.x;
            newShadow.x = bikeX + 150; //109.8;
            //ANITMATING THE DRIVER!!!!
            if( currRotation <= -11 ){ //This should occur at a lower
                rider.gotoAndPlay ( "sitDown" );
                sitDown = true;
                newShadow.gotoAndStop ( "fullShadow" );
            }
            if( currRotation <= -15 ){
                newShadow.gotoAndStop( "three4thShadow" );
                leanBack = true;
            }
            //just change shadow with this one
            if( currRotation <= -25 ){
                newShadow.gotoAndStop ( "midShadow" );
            }
            if( currRotation <= -30 ){
                rider.gotoAndPlay ( "LeanBack" );
                leanBack = true;
                newShadow.gotoAndStop ( "smallShadow" );
            }
            if( currRotation <= -34 ){ //Highest
                rider.gotoAndPlay ( "LeanBack2" );
                leanBack = true;
                newShadow.gotoAndStop ( "smallestShadow" );
            }
            if( currRotation <= -35 ){ //Highest
                rider.gotoAndPlay ( "LeanBack2" );
                leanBack = true;
                newShadow.gotoAndStop ( "allTheWayBack" );
            }
            //if player holds or hit the brake
            if( pressedBrake == "yes" ) { //for some reason the opposite is working right now
                var currBikePosition:int;
                currBikePosition = bitmapBike.rotation;
                bitmapBike.rotation += 2;
                currBikePosition = 0;
            }
            //gravity pulling bike down
            bitmapBike.rotation += gravity*timePassed/1000;
            bitmapBike.rotation += gravity*timePassed/1000;
            //if player holding gas, do wheeliez
            if( holdGas == true ){
                //Make bike wheelie
                bitmapBike.rotation -= dy*timePassed/1000;
                rider.rotation -= dy*timePassed/1000;
            }
            //Move Bike to center, then move buildings
            if( bitmapBike.x <=187 ){
                //move bike
                bitmapBike.x += dx*timePassed/1000;
            }else{
                //move buildings and background
                building1.x += buildingDx*timePassed/1000;
                building2.x += buildingDx*timePassed/1000;
                //buildings
                if( building1.x <= -25 ){
                    building1.x = building2.x + building1.width;
                }else if( building2.x <= -25 ){
                    building2.x = building1.x + building2.width;
                }
                background1.x += backgroundDx*timePassed/1000;
                background2.x += backgroundDx*timePassed/1000;
                //background
                if( background1.x <=0 ){
                    background1.x = background2.x + background1.width;
                }else if ( background2.x <=0 ){
                    background2.x = background1.x + background2.width;
                }
            }
```

Comment: If I understood it correct, you experience the lag even without gas? My best guess is the way you're treating the moving background. Try to remove that the background is moving and then try to remove the background completely and see what happens and report back :) In general, nothing is clearly wrong with your code. You might need to remove "cacheAsBitmap" since that causes extra work unless you have a complex shape. This seems like a "trial & error" approach, so just try to remove some stuff and see when it is working correctly

Comment: @DanielMesSer thanks for your help. The game actually runs pretty smooth until these buttons are pressed. (Including the building movement) It then lags. Before the buttons are pressed the background my stutter a bit periodically but nothing detrimental. Definitely not as close as it does when the buttons are pressed. I took the buildings out and the game looked great. I'm going to try moving them incrementing the x using += instead of time and see how that works. Any other method you can think of?

Comment: @DanielMesSer moving the buildings x using += turned out to be 10x worst. Everything pretty much come to a stand still when the buttons are pressed. Using the += method depends on the frame rate. If it comes to a stand still im guessing the buttons are slowing down the frame rate out

Answer (score 0):

How are you handling the masking of "background image"? How big is the image?

Most likely the drop is due to you having to redraw EVERYTHING when your bike moves since it can no longer reuse the old values of the cached bitmap. And since your background is HUGE this causes the performance drop you notice.

As a start, you should probably define a **scrollRect** on the "gigantic moving background" instead of just drawing the entire background. This causes only the part of image being shown to be sent to GPU. Such as `bg.scrollRect = new Rectangle(offsetX,offsetY, 1280, 1024);`

read http://gskinner.com/blog/archives/2006/11/understanding_d.html for a short introduction to scrollRect.

CacheAsBitmap might not be doing what you want it to do, if you are changing the look of a displayobject over each frame, you would actually loose performance since you first have to draw the items, then put them into a bitmap, and then draw that bitmap. Then on the next frame, you would end up redoing the exact same thing (since the old cached bitmap is no longer valid). cacheAsBitmap is very useful for when you have complex vector shapes that remain the same for an amount of frames.

For a more comprehensive optimization guideline, read the following two massive pdf-files:
http://help.adobe.com/en_US/as3/mobile/flashplatform_optimizing_content.pdf
http://help.adobe.com/en_US/as3/dev/as3_devguide.pdf

Comment: I think it's the frame rate. I tested the game using Adobe Scout and noticed drops in the frame rate a significant amount each time the mouse down event fired. IT would pick up and stay at its set rate until the button is clicked again. I switched the mouse down event into keyboard event and the game runs perfect using the keys instead of the buttons. (Even on the computer i could see the lag when the buttons were pressed) . When i used the keyboard events Scout showed that my frame rate was still at its set rate. I also used the accelerometer to move the bike . There was still no lag.

Comment: I've even set my display object's mouse properties to false. This didn't help either

Comment: I found a great EASY Fix for me and my games was just to make sure on all vector graphics symbols I cached as bitmap,  and The big fix for me was when I set SWF publish settings, Hardware Acceleration to GPU and also in my android manifest <renderMode>gpu</renderMode>  this worked awesome and turned my large graphic very laggy game into a fast and smooth running game.

Answer (score 0):

in Publish setting set your Hardware acceleration to GPU, that will lean off the processor